# How do I get zipcodes from longitude and latitude on python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopy

I have a data frame of latitude and longitude coordinates on this CSV file:[Longlat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jGDBV3upBUIOzrhsm_4XaOzsII990u9/view?usp=sharing).

I used this code to try to get the zipcodes:

```
import copy

def get_zipcode(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field):
    location = geolocator.reverse((df[lat_field], df[lon_field]))
    return location.raw['address']['postcode']


geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent='myusername') #My OpenMap username

zipcodes = longlat.apply(get_zipcode, axis=1, geolocator=geolocator, lat_field=longlat['LATITUDE_X'], lon_field=longlat['LONGITUDE_X'])
```

I got the error:

```
KeyError
"None of [Float64Index([39.0962320000896, 39.1462010000896, 39.1347670000896,\n 39.1076250000897, 39.0928490000897, 39.1648900000896,\n 39.1846440000895, 39.0970790000897, 39.1491220000896,\n 39.1145560000896,\n ...\n 39.1039560000896,
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in the latitude and longitude `Series` instead of the latitude and longitude column names.

```
import geopy
import pandas as pd

def get_zipcode(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field):
    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse((df[lat_field], df[lon_field]))
        return location.raw['address']['postcode']
    except (AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError):
        print(repr(e), df[lat_field], df[lon_field])
        return None



longlat = pd.read_csv('longlat.csv', sep='\t')
geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent='myusername') #My OpenMap username

# Change this
# zipcodes = longlat.apply(
#     get_zipcode, axis=1,geolocator=geolocator, 
#     lat_field=longlat['LATITUDE_X'], lon_field=longlat['LONGITUDE_X'])

# To this
zipcodes = longlat.apply(
    get_zipcode, axis=1, geolocator=geolocator, 
    lat_field='LATITUDE_X', lon_field='LONGITUDE_X')


print(zipcodes)
```

Output:

```
0    45233-4555
1    45212-2609
2    45229-3018
3         45202
4         45230
...
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm having the error:
key error 'postcode'

Comment: Obviously it can't find a code for that coord, wrap the `return location.raw['address']['postcode']`  in a try: except:

Comment: I got the error:
`Must be a coordinate pair or Point`

Can I get the zipcodes from the shapefile of Ohio instead of this method?

Comment: How about you post more complete code. I ran the code in my answer on a portion of your csv and it works.

Comment: Are you on kaggle? I can share the notes with you so that you can see what I'm trying to do. The datasets are quite large.

Comment: No I'm not. Like I said, wrap the `return location.raw['address']['postcode']` in a `try: except:` and `return None`.  If I don't use a `try:except:` I get the `ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point` error when `df[lat_field or lon_field]` is empty and you have a *lot* of rows with empty `LATITUDE_X LONGITUDE_X`. You could also just drop those rows https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629362/737471

Comment: How do I wrap `return location.raw['address']['postcode']` in a `try: except`?

Comment: I have dropped the empty rows, but I get the error `AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raw'`

Although I did not use the `try:except:`

Comment: Just catch the exception like I said. That way you can figure out what your problem is. It's basic debugging...

Comment: How do I catch the exception? Please

Comment: With a `try:except:`